# passing karate.env by command line doesn't work as expected

Tags: environment-variables, karate

I downloaded the karate-demo project and made this small changes:

in karate-config.js
the first line of the function:

```
karate.log("Environment from command line: ",karate.env);
```

then I execute from terminal

```
mvn test -Dtest=InfoRunner -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=web"
```

in the output I should get:

```
Environment from command line: web
```

but it shown :

```
Environment from command line: null
```

for some reason is not passing the karate.env variable

Comment: i found out that work if execute the following command
    mvn test -Dtest=InfoRunner -Dkarate.env=web

Answer (score 2):

When you remove `-dargline` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for mentioning this:

> i found out that work if execute the following command mvn test -Dtest=InfoRunner -Dkarate.env=web

This is actually news to me. Can you provide your maven / java version ? Also maybe your local maven installation has been modified ?

For example:

```
$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T13:28:13+05:30)
Maven home: /Users/<>/dev/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.8.0_112, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: this is what i have:

    `codesnippets git:(master) mvn -version
    Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T13:33:14-05:00)
    Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.4/libexec
    Java version: 1.8.0_172, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: 
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"`